# How to implement a server-side querying solution for mongo db references

Tags: php, mongodb

I am relatively new to Mongo DB, but I am finding that is merges nicely with a project that I am working on. I am currently stuck at a problem however that I am really struggling to resolve...

This is specifically related to mongo db's "manual" references, documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references

The project that I am working on sees every single document as a re-usable object instance, meaning that it can be embedded within another document, and because I am using manual references along with the client-side to resolve the references, it works really well. The issue arises when I want to be able to find objects, based on the value of one of the child objects.

A likely scenario:

- we have an Orders collection which stores generated shop orders. An order object has a property named "products" which when viewed in mongo db is an array of references to product objects.
- we also have a Products collection which stores products that can be used in orders.
- say we want to be able to find all orders that contain the product "foo-bar", and bearing in mind that the path `order.products` is an array of references (not the embedded objects), what would be the most efficient way to do this? The most ideal solution would be the ability to simply use `order.products.name : 'foo-bar'`

A few additional notes:

- fetching all order objects from the database and having the client-side resolve the objects to filter out the ones that we're looking for is far too inefficient.
- embedding the product documents inside of the order documents is not an option, as it is essential to be able to modify the order and product documents independently of each other.
- I am accessing mongo db using a PHP framework (and the official mongo db php extension)
- a server-side solution would be ideal

I have briefly looked into the ability to write custom functions on mongo's server-side, but I can't quite tell if that would be a potential way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to use joins (a term from SQL). Mongodb has no support for joins or alternative techniques.

The simplest thing that can work here is two-step query (pseudo-code)

```
product_ids = db.products.find(name: 'foo-bar').only('id')
orders = db.orders.find(product_id: {$in: product_ids})
```

This way you don't download a bunch of product objects onto the client, only their ids. It works quite well for me in my apps.

But this task is, of course, much better handled by a real relational DB.

Comment: Yeah, I come from the RBDMS environment but was finding mongodb really nice for handling an objective data structure... i am slowly verging towards the same conclusion, in that relational is the correct tool for the job... thanks a lot for the response